# Saving matrix values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I saved matrix values onto a .mat file for later use. The matrix size is 5.6kx3.4k. The values inside the matrix range from 0-10k. When I saved the matrix using - `save(x.mat)`, the size was around 80MB. However, when I equated the same matrix to another matrix `b = x;` and then saved that matrix as a .mat file, the size increases, sometimes by a large margin. Why does this happen?

Also, am I doing something wrong in the way I am saving these matrices?

Comment: Can you provide the exact code you are using to save the b matrix and the x matrix? If it's really just save(x.mat), then you are saving your whole workspace, which explains the size increase when you add the large b matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (equivalent) commands

```
save('x.mat')
save x.mat
```

tell MATLAB to save the entire contents of the workspace in a file called "x.mat" - so if you do

```
>> x = randn(5000, 100);
>> save('x.mat');
```

you will get a file of some size, and if you then do

```
>> b = x;
>> save('x.mat');
```

your file will roughly double in size, because you now have two matrices (`x` and `b`) being saved in it.

If you want to save a particular variable, you can do

```
>> save('x.mat', 'x');
>> save('b.mat', 'b');
```

which will create two files "x.mat" and "b.mat" which contain `x` and `b` respectively. Of course, there is no requirement that the file names match the variable names - doing

```
>> save('unicorn.mat', 'x');
>> save('apricot.mat', 'b');
```

which will create two files "unicorn.mat" and "apricot.mat" which contain `x` and `b` respectively.